# jQuery Animation - Multiple Elements

Tags: jquery, animation, transition, show-hide, slideup

I have been trying to achieve an effect on a webpage which I have achieved once, but I want to apply it to multiple page sections. However I'm having an issue with positioning and getting the desired animation

I'm using jQuery and the slideUp method. I have the following code;

```
(function() {

    var pageEl = $('div.first-layer');

    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        pageEl.slideUp(1300, function() { $(document).off('scroll').remove(); });
    });
})();
```

This has the desired effect;

[image]

As you can see I have managed to achieve this animation once with the above code but I want to be able to apply this effect on scroll, with 3 different elements.

My idea was to attach an id/class and for each class have a different scroll event attached to it, when it reaches the desired scroll point for each class/id hide the other 2 elements.

If anyone could point in the right direction or offer some advice It would be appreciated. Been stuck on this for a while now. If you would like more information please just ask.

Thank you.

edit: I have created a JSFiddle, for you to see what I' trying to achieve;
https://jsfiddle.net/tdatkxrf/4/

Comment: post your full code or create fiddle

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No worries, I'm creating a plunkr as we speak. Kind of hard to show you the source code as it's a pretty big.

Comment: you could look at a slider example and implement it on the scroll event. it's basically the same thing.

Comment: Hi Spluf, If you don't mind can you elaborate please? Maybe an example or a solution? Thanks.

Comment: still working on it but here's what I am going for: https://plnkr.co/edit/02mko4f5ZSqSDLtlvDwR?p=preview

Comment: Hey Spluff feels a lot smoother! Nice. Can't wait to see your final outcome. I'm also having a play around with the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, depending on how you want it to trigger the event you might have to play a bit more with it, right now it's extra sensitive, but here it is:

**Edit:** on Plunkr I have modified the sensitivity by adding a new variable that counts  the scrolling. I will leave this as it is so you can see both implementation (plunker with the variable, answer without).
plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/02mko4f5ZSqSDLtlvDwR?p=preview

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: helvetica;">jQuery slideUp</h1>
    <div class="container" style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column; position: relative; background: grey;">
      <div id="section-one" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; background: #cc6699;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: helvetica;">Section One</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="section-two" style="display:none; height: 300px; width: 300px; background: #cc9966;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: helvetica;">Section Two</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="section-three" style="display: none; height: 300px; width: 300px; background: #6699cc;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: helvetica;">Section Three</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

jQuery:

```
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function() {

  var e1  = $('#section-one');
  var e2 = $('#section-two');
  var e3 = $('#section-three');

  var sections = [e1, e2, e3];

$('.container').bind('mousewheel', function(e){scrollCheck(e);});

var scrollCheck = function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
      for(i= 0; i<sections.length;i++){
        j=i-1;
        if(sections[i].attr('display') != "none" && i > 0){
          sections[i].slideUp(1300);
          sections[i].attr('display', "none");
          sections[j].slideDown(1300);
          sections[j].attr('display', "");
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      for(i= 0; i<sections.length;i++){
        j=i+1;
        if(sections[i].attr('display') != "none" && i+1 < sections.length){
          sections[i].slideUp(1300);
          sections[i].attr('display', "none");
          sections[j].slideDown(1300);
          sections[j].attr('display', "");
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

there are also some packages to detect the mousewheel events, you might want to have a look at one of those.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me how to do this, I will implement it into my project. But aa you said it is a bit sensitive at the moment How would I tone it down, so that the user doesn't accidentally scroll all sections at the same time? Thank you once again though I really appreciate it.

Comment: the easiest way would be to replace the scroll event with arrow keys, this way you don't have to check if you have a scroll bar or how many scrolls  should equal a page slide. Also, the mouse wheel packages might have some handlers for this (never used one before). I am also still working on that plunker, so I will let you know when I get something working.

Comment: I just found this package that does the same thing but better than I did, seams easy to use from what I've been reading in their documentation. Have a look here: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: I have also toned the scrolling down a bit, you can check the implementation on plunker. good luck ;)

Comment: thanks Spluf, I really liked your implementation as the fullPage.js doesn't have the feel to it I want, I mean it's a really good plugin but it's essentially a slider :p, this way you can animate each individual section. Instead of it just going from left to right or up to down. That's why i was using the slideUp method in jQuery. Thanks for your help though very much appreciated.